# How do you select min(string_col) using a JPA Criteria query?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, criteria

JPA Criteria seems to insist that min() (and max()) are only applicable to Numeric fields. However, this is NOT the case as SQL database can indeed select min() and max() values from a string column. I can also use JQL to select the min() or max() value of a string column.

However, when using Criteria queries, the compiler complains when min() is used with a string column:
Bound mismatch: The generic method min(Expression) of type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (subquery.get("string_column")). The inferred type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

This query works:

```
"select new com.epsilon.totalfact.web.api.model.UPCDetails" +
"(u.id, d.name as dimension, c.name as category, u.name, u.description," +
" u.keywords, u.userNotes,  u.restrictedResellerFlag, u.hidden," +
" (select min(p.rateId) from u.platforms p)" +
"  || case when (select min(p.rateId) from u.platforms p) != (select max(p.rateId) from u.platforms p) then concat(' ~ ',(select max(p.rateId) from u.platforms p)) else '' end" +
"  as deRateId" +
" )" +
" from UPC u " +
" join u.category c" +
" join c.dimension d" +
" order by d.name, c.name, u.name",
```

and this criteria query has the above mentioned error:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<UPCDetails> query = cb.createQuery(UPCDetails.class);
Root<UPC> u = query.from(UPC.class);
Join<UPC, Category> c = u.join("category");
Join<UPC, Dimension> d = c.join("dimension");

Subquery<String> sub = query.subquery(Number.class);
Root<UPC> subRoot = sub.from(UPC.class);
SetJoin<UPC,Platform> subPlatform = subRoot.join(UPC_.platforms);
sub.select(cb.min(subPlatform.get("rateId")));
```

Comment: The error message says it all: It's only implemented for Number types, even though as you point out in SQL `min()` and `max()` work with most types, such as text, date, boolean, etc.

Comment: A very quick look at something that looks like documentation suggests that `least` and `greatest` are used instead of `min` and `max` for other data types. (They are aggregate functions, unlike SQL where they are not aggregate functions.)

Answer (score 0):

mathguy provided the answer, you need to use `least()` and `greatest()` instead of `min()` and `max()` for strings and other types.